# ActiveMQ replicatedLevelDB cant run

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

There are 3 ZKs on three different VMs and on each of them running ActiveMQ. When I'm using as persistenceAdapter ***kahaDB*** then everything works fine

but if I use ***replicatedLevelDB*** then when I starting activemq then I'm getting error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jute.Record
...


   Wrapper Stopped
```

I configured activemq.xml like this:

```
<broker brokerName="broker" persistent="true" ... >
  ...
  <persistenceAdapter>
    <replicatedLevelDB
         directory="activemq-data" />
         replicas="3"
         bind="tcp://0.0.0.0;0"
         zkAddress="zoo1.example.org:2181,zoo2.example.org:2181,zoo3.example.org:2181"
         zkPassword="password"
         zkPath="/activemq/leveldb-stores"
         />
  </persistenceAdapter>
  ...
</broker>
```

Comment: For what it's worth the ActiveMQ documentation notes that the LevelDB store is deprecated. See https://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.

Comment: I know that its deprecated but does it mean that will it not work anymore ?

Comment: My understanding is that it never worked particularly well and the fact that it is deprecated (and has been deprecated for almost 3 years now) means that you're not likely to find much help for it.

Comment: I got you. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The LevelDB support in the ActiveMQ broker is deprecated and has not been maintained in any fashion for a few years now.  The error would seem to indicate that you are missing some code from ZooKeeper which could either mean your deployment is missing that jar or the broker dependencies are now at fault and aren't pulling along the right bits.  In any case I'd recommend against using the LeveDB functionality as it is not production ready and will likely be pulled in the next major release.